# AngularJS- store initial value in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to make an editable input directive, that can indicate if entered value is other than initial value. By initial value I mean value that is set on start from GET request.

Currently it works like this:

**editable-input-directive.js**

```
angular
  .module("shared.directives")

  .directive("editableInput", function() {
    return {
      require: "?ngModel",
      scope: {
        value: "@"
      },
      restrict: "E",
      template:
        '<div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input ng-model='value' ng-change='onChange()'>
            <i class="icon ion-edit"></i>
         </div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return;
        scope.onChange = function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.value);
        };

        ngModel.$render = function() {
          scope.value = ngModel.$modelValue;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Using directive:

```
<editable-input ng-model="phone" value={{accountData.phone}}></editable-input>
```

I am getting accountData.phone, after making HTTP get request. Then I would like to store it in directive as initial value and indicate changes.

For example:

Value from HTTP GET : 123456 <-- that is original one

Value after edit : 1234567 <-- that is different than initial, so indicate it (for example apply blue background etz. )

Value after edit : 123456 <--- that is the same as initial value, so don't indicate it

How to achieve that? Appreciate your help here.

Comment: There is already $pristine property. And your use of ng-model... is completely wrong (i.e. you have 2 ng-models for one field - which is weird). And this directive will never be usable... Better just diont(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require the initial value once it has changed, `ng-model` comes built in with functionality to handle this.

For example, when the `ng-model` directive is applied to an input field, when the value differs to what was initially applied to the input box, `myForm.fieldName.$dirty` becomes `true`.

As well as that, the class `ng-dirty` is applied to the control, so you can style your CSS accordingly (eg. apply a blue background).

There are others states too, such as `$pristine`, `$touched` etc.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel for more details.

Hope this helps.